# I have an infinite solution to an ODE even though it has only a regular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity-theory

I have the ODE:
$\displaystyle y''(x)+\frac{y'(x)}{x+1}+y(x)=0$

I know that this has a regular singular point at $x=-1$, as $(1+x)^{-1}$ has only a first order pole, and $1$ has no pole at all, and therefore I expect that it should have a non-singular (finite) solution (or so Riley,Hobson,Bence tells me).

Yet, the solution:

$\displaystyle y(x)=\frac{Y_0(2) J_0(x+1)-J_0(2) Y_0(x+1)}{J_0(1) Y_0(2)-J_0(2) Y_0(1)}$

tends to $\infty$ as $\rightarrow -1$. I'm therefore confused... can anybody resolve why this is?